# Create a new dict with combo key & value from 1 dict and value from another dict

Tags: python, dictionary

I was given 2 dicts,

```
# dict format - bookID:title
dict1 = {'book1':'Lord of the Rings','book2':'Animal Farm','book3':'Lilliput'}

# dict format - bookID_gender:rating
dict2 = {'book1_F':5, 'book2_M':4, 'book1_M':3, 'book1_M':2}
```

I want to match by bookID between the 2 dicts and calculate the average rating by title and gender to output,

```
book1 - Lord of the Rings - F - 5.0
book1 - Lord of the Rings - M - 2.5
book2 - Animal Farm - M - 4
book3 - Lilliput - no rating
```

I initially thought of splitting the combo key in dict2 but got the error splitting cannot be done on dict keys.

***Edit***

```
for bookid, title in dict1.items():
    if bookid == dict2.keys().spilt('_')[0]:
        print('test ok')
    else:
        print('test not ok')
```

error message was,

```
    if bookid == dict2.keys().spilt('_')[0]:
AttributeError: 'dict_keys' object has no attribute 'spilt'
```

I am very new to Python with very limited knowledge in Python's tuple, list and dicts.  How should I tackle this in order to get the expected result? Sample code is very much appreciated.

Thanks, Lobbie

Comment: Please let us know what you have tried, or the code you have written. We would then try to help you out on where the problem is.

Comment: thanks and updated with one of the code I tried and am still stuck.

Comment: dict2.keys() is a list and will not have split function. Split function is available only for string. Hence, you would have to loop through dict2.keys(), and for each item you would have to use split, and compare it. Also please note, you have a spelling mistake in split.

Comment: The elements of `dict_keys()` which is a list not a string, have `split` function, not the `dict_keys()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Corrected the code.

```
# dict format - bookID:title
dict1 = {'book1':'Lord of the Rings','book2':'Animal Farm','book3':'Lilliput'}

# dict format - bookID_gender:rating
dict2 = {'book1_F':5, 'book2_M':4, 'book1_M':3, 'book1_M':2}

for bookid, title in dict1.items():
    for bookid_1 in dict2.keys():
        if bookid == bookid_1.split('_')[0]:
            print('test ok')
        else:
            print('test not ok')
```

**Output**

```
test ok
test ok
test not ok
test not ok
test not ok
test ok
test not ok
test not ok
test not ok
```

Comment: thank you very much. but if I replace print('test ok') with print('%s-%s-%s) % (bookid_1, title, rating), I get SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal.  How should I fixed this please?

Comment: You seem to be missing a single apostrophe in the print, it should be print('%s-%s-%s') % (bookid_1, title, rating)

Comment: Yes, found it and change my code to `for bookid, title in dict1.items():
    for bookid_1, rating in dict2.items():
        if bookid == bookid_1.split('_')[0]:
            print("%s-%s-%s-%s" % (bookid, bookid_1, title, rating))
        else:
            print("%s-%s-%s" % (bookid, title, 'no rating'))`.  book3 should be the only book without rating but I got, `book2-Animal Farm-no rating
book2-Animal Farm-no rating
book2-book2_M-Animal Farm-4
book3-Lilliput-no rating
book3-Lilliput-no rating
book3-Lilliput-no rating`. is there a way to rectify this? =(

Comment: In Python dictionaries, the Key should be unique. In the data you have used book1_M twice. The new value overwrites it. That is the reason why it goes into the else part.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `dict.keys()` function to get the keys of `dict2`, like:

```
>>> dict2.keys()
['book1_F', 'book1_M', 'book2_M']
```

Then, you can splitting the combo keys such as:

```
>>> for value in dict2.keys():
...     value.split('_')[0]
... 
'book1'
'book1'
'book2'
```

Comment: thanks for your help too in teaching me how to split a combo key. 谢谢。